# get image name on submit pressed without uploading image

Tags: javascript, php

is it possible to get the name of an image after submit has been pressed? 
I have an upload page (.php file) which uses some javascript to grab the filename but once the submit is pressed it doesnt retain the filename and I just get an empty alert box.
After submit has been pressed I want either javascript to get the filename or php to get the filename so it can be saved to my database. Here is the code I have at present.

```
?>
<script>
//get uploaded image name after submit pressed
$('#file-upload').ready(function(){
  var fu1 = document.getElementById("file-upload").value;
  fName = fu1.split("\\").pop();
  alert(fName);
})
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: There's not really enough code here to be sure what's going on. What do you do with `fname` once the "submit" button (which we also can't see) is pressed? Also are you saying that `alert(fName)` within the code you've shown is empty? Because that's an alert, but it doesn't appear to occur after a submit, yet you haven't shown any other alerts. So it's a bit confusing. Please show us enough JavaScript and PHP code so we can understand your process, and know precisely where the issue occurs. Thanks.

Comment: It is ok now, I managed to get the file name using localStorage.setItem() and localStorage.getItem(). The only problem now is that javascript has the variable and not the php but that would require me posting another question. I will do some research before I go any further. thnkx

Comment: Broadly, if you want to send data to the server (and thus to PHP), you have to make a HTTP request. In a browser there are 3 standard ways to do that: 1) submit a form, 2) navigate to a new URL (and pass querystring values), 3) make an AJAX request. You could use any one of those. They can all be initiated via JavaScript if necessary. Methods 1 and 2 refresh the whole page (and/or load a different page afterwards), whereas method 3 lets the browser stay on the same page and just sends a separate request to the server.

Comment: yes I am not sure what one to go with, basically I am using a drag n drop image upload with the option to upload from dir. The page also has other input fields with one textarea. When someone uploads an image to their browser it is not sent until the submit button is pressed where upon the image is finally uploaded to the server and other input fields are saved.

Comment: In that case you need either option 1 or 3. But I can't tell you which one to use. It depends what you want to do next, and/or what kind of user experience you want to create.

Comment: P.S. Unless you want to submit the file name in a **separate** request, before you submit the file itself, then you don't need to use the code you've shown in the question. When you upload a file, the name is automatically visible to the server at the same time.

Comment: I am looking at option 3, seems a little more easier to work with(i think). Would rather it all be set on one submission preferably. Because of the way the whole script and db has been scripted doing the photo upload separate from the input fields would require a total script re-work

Comment: Well you could still have two uploads, if you really want. There could be sensible UX reasons to do that, maybe, although it's certainly not essential. But again the filename would still automatically be transmitted with the file, and so the server could capture it at that time. There would still be no need to send the filename separately really (and besides, the user could potentially change their mind in between requests!).

Comment: I never thought about the filename being sent separately from the actual file? ok, I am going to give this a total re-think. thnks

Comment: "I never thought about the filename being sent separately from the actual file"...well I assumed that was what the purpose your original code was? Trying to extract the filename without actually uploading the file? That's basically what the title of your question is asking. But yeah you don't need to do it, anyway.

Comment: I meant on submitting the image, I was worried in case it would only upload the name without the actual image. this can get a bit confusing trying to explain :)

Comment: No, don't worry if you upload the image, it uploads the name as well. And the default behaviour is to upload the image, if it's part of the form.